# Programming Phoenix: where is this 'assigns' coming from?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I found a clause in 'app.html.eex' auto-created by elixir phoenix:

```
<main role="main">
   <%= render @view_module, @view_template, assigns %>
</main>
```

but where is this keyword map 'assigns' coming from?

Comment: In your controller, when you do `render conn, "index.html", key: :value`, the assigns will be populated with the `key: :value` pair, as well as anywhere you call `assign(conn, :other_key, :other_value)`. The actual assigns are held in the `conn`. You just get convenient access to them in the templates.

Comment: @JustinWood I know, but this app.html.eex is auto-generated by phoenix itself, I am wondering where this variable assigns is coming from. It must be somewhere in the source code of phoenix.

Comment: Are you asking where in the phoenix library code it generates the `assigns` variable? Because that reads differently from your question.

Comment: `assigns` just refers to `conn.assigns`. Unless I am misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @JustinWood Yes, I'm asking where assigns variable is from phoenix library. Thx. My bad.

Comment: You can find the `render` function [here](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L677). Feel free to follow through the code. I'm not 100% what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`assigns` is a template-context local variable declared via [hygiene bypassing](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#macros-hygiene) in the [template compile-time](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/914b8e500c6b10d8863d5babdcf8b1797e4b0561/lib/phoenix/template.ex#L356).

Comment: Thx. Could u pls give us some more details about this process in the source code of phoenix ?

Comment: I have phoenix source code, where it is defined, linked.

Answer (score 0):

per the docs [Phoenix.View.hmtl](https://web.archive.org/web/20171112110024/https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3)

**Assigns**

"Assigns are meant to be user data that will be available in templates. However, there are keys under assigns that are specially handled by Phoenix, they are:

:layout - tells Phoenix to wrap the rendered result in the given layout. See next section.
The following assigns are reserved, and cannot be set directly:

@view_module - The view module being rendered
@view_template - The @view_module’s template being rendered "

assigns is a property on the conn object designed to add data to pass around like options.

assigns itself is coming @conn.assigns,
in any controller you can play around with this by
adding this code to a controllers index

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.PageController do
  use MyAppWeb, :controller

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn = assign(conn, :thing, "this is not a taco")
    render conn, "index.html"
  end
end
```

then in app.html.eex add this line

```
<%= assigns.thing %>
```

then you should see "this is not a taco" when you hit the controllers index, "/" in this example

if you add this line to your controller you can see it in your server

```
...
    conn = assign(conn, :thing, "this is not a taco")
    IO.inspect(conn.assigns)
...
```

I have most commonly seen this used to set a user to assigns to have access in the views like this
...plugs/set_user

```
 def init(_params) do
 end

 def call(conn, _params) do
    if conn.assigns[:user] do
      conn
    else
      user_id = get_session(conn, :user_id)

      cond do
        user = user_id && Repo.get(User, user_id) ->
          assign(conn, :user, user)
        true ->
          assign(conn, :user, nil)
      end
    end
 end
```

...view/html

```
  <%= if @conn.assigns.user do %>
      Hello, <%= @conn.assigns.user.first_name %>!       
  <% else %>
  ... do something else
  <% end %>
```

to assign value you use 'assign'

to get the values you use 'assigns'

[docs on Plug.conn](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html)